# moment-timezone не переводит время в указанный часовой пояс

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Пытаюсь с помощью moment-timezone получить время в указанной тайм зоне.

```
     const currentDate = moment().tz('Europe/Moscow').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
```

но получаю локальное время ПК.
На ПК стоит часовой пояс +4, нужная таймзона +3.
Получить сначала в UTC и потом перевести в таймзону или перевести конкретное время в нужную таймзону так же не увенчались успехом.
В доке указан именно такой способ перевода, просьба уточнить, что я делаю не так.

Comment: Надо дополнить вoпрос значением переменной `timezone`, или оформить код как [repro].

Answer (score 0):

Не актуально, пытался сделать странное. Фронт в итоге все равно время получает локальное, через браузер, чтобы сделать иначе нужно обращаться по сети или к некому ресурсу, или как я и сделал, делать получение на бэкенде, у сервера статичный часовой пояс, где можно получать что-то по умолчанию и уже потом гонять по часовым поясам.